# Alternative of box-shadow

Tags: css

I want to give the box-shadow in my email but this property is not supported by gmail and yahoo then is there in any alternative trick to give box-shadow in the mail?

if yes then please inform me as soon as possible

Comment: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only possibilities are:

1. A single image with a box-shadow
2. Box-shadow-like images on the edges of the element to simulate a box-shadow

That's it I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Gmail does not support full HTML email footers, I did alot of research into the subject. YOu may already know the ins-and-outs of building a strong email footer, but if you don't; check out Campaign Monitor's blog.

To the point, a box shadow will need to be achieved either by using an image (which I do not suggest as most images are blocked by default unless you're trusted by the Gmail user).

The other alternative is a colour filled cell placed along the edge of whatever box you're attempting to create a shadow against – still very rudimentary. My solution would be that of graceful degradation, make your design work well regardless of what the user has enabled – though if they have everything you need enabled, they get a sexier experience of course!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I was in need of a crisp shadow on responsive buttons, so in my case, I was able to emulate this with a `faux-shadow` class div directly under my button. I used border-radius to make them look more 'button-like'. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRrbLp

Comment: Amazing, hands down, best solution that works across the highest chunk of email providers!